# Using a LinkedHashSet to store random numbers but has duplicates

Tags: java, android, arraylist, set, linkedhashset

I have an app that generates a random arithmetic expression. It then generates a correct answer in a random position (`tag`) and three subsequent incorrect answers allowing the user to choose.

I originally went with an `ArrayList` but it provides duplicates. I then converted the `ArrayList` contents in the `for loop` to a `Set` and it still produced duplicates. I then changed the initial `ArrayList` to a `LinkedHashSet` and alas, still duplicates. i'm thinking it might be the placement in my `for loop` but I've tried messing around with position and I either encounter duplicates or `Index` problems.

I don't want to use `Java 8`'s:`List<String> deDupStringList3 = strList.stream().distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());` as it's `API/Version` specific.

`For Loop` Code:

```
    List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>(new HashSet<Integer>(5));
    answers.clear();

    int incorrectAnswer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i == locCorrectAnswer) {
                answers.add(value);
            } else {
                if (operator == '+') {
                    incorrectAnswer = value + rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                } else {
                    incorrectAnswer = value - rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                }
                while (incorrectAnswer == value) {
                    if (operator == '+') {
                        incorrectAnswer = value + rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    } else {
                        incorrectAnswer = value - rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    }
                }
                answers.add(incorrectAnswer);
            }
    }
```

`For Loop` code (with `ArrayList` and conversion to `Set`):

```
    ArrayList <Integer> answers;
    Set<Integer> s = new LinkedHashSet<>(answers);

    int incorrectAnswer;

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (i == locCorrectAnswer) {
                answers.add(value);
            } else {
                if (operator == '+') {
                    incorrectAnswer = value + rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                } else {
                    incorrectAnswer = value - rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                }
                while (incorrectAnswer == value) {
                    if (operator == '+') {
                        incorrectAnswer = value + rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    } else {
                        incorrectAnswer = value - rand.nextInt(10) + 1;
                    }
                }
                answers.add(incorrectAnswer);
            }
            s.addAll(answers);
            answers.clear();
            answers.addAll(s);
    }
```

I'm sure its a simple error but I can't see it.

Comment: The general pattern you should follow is to iterate in a loop and generate incorrect answers, adding them to a _set_, until the set has 3 incorrect answers.

Comment: Now what's the downvote for?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I want the correct answer and incorrect answers to be in random locations. Would that still work with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the following.

```
Set<Integer> s = new HashSet<>();
//correct value
s.add(value);
while (s.size() < 4)
{
    //incorrect value
    s.add( value + rand.nextInt(10) + 1);
}
List<Integer> answers = new ArrayList<>(s);
//shuffle
Collections.shuffle(answers);
```

Comment: I used your answer but omitted the `shuffle` and implemented it with a `LinkedHashSet`, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just create your Set of answers like this:

```
Set<String> answers = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

Now every value can be there just 1 time. It can be added without getting an error but it will be only one time in the list.
And you can still iterate/loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

You're still calling `answers.addAll(s)` in the loop. While there won't be any duplicates in `s` in any given iteration, you will still get duplicates from different iterations.

Since you don't want any duplicates, there's no reason to use `List`s in the first place. Any `Set` will remove duplicates, and `LinkedHashSet` will preserve insertion order.